# Loop to check user's input for empty space

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment to write an application that will take an input from the user, and store each answer in a String array. This application must also check the user's input for an empty value and re-prompt the user to enter their answer. The application must repeat ONLY the empty question, as there is scope for this application to take 50 questions.

Here is my code so far:

```
for(iLoop=0; iLoop<noOfQuest; iLoop++)
        {
            if(noOfEmails<1)
            {
                System.out.println("FILE_ERROR: Please ensure line \"noOfEmails\" is more than 0");
            }
            if(noOfQuest==1)
            {
                System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(finalMess);
            }
            if(noOfQuest==2)
            {
                System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                System.out.println(questionArr[1]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(finalMess);
            }
            if(noOfQuest==3)
            {
                System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(questionArr[1]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                System.out.println(questionArr[2]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(finalMess);
            }
            if(noOfQuest==4)
            {
                System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(questionArr[1]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(questionArr[2]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                System.out.println(questionArr[3]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(finalMess);
            }
            if(noOfQuest==5)
            {
                System.out.println(questionArr[0]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(questionArr[1]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(questionArr[2]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(questionArr[3]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(prefinalMess);
                System.out.println(questionArr[3]);
                ansArray[iLoop]=ans.next();
                System.out.println(finalMess);
            }
        }
```

I must also develop methods to check the input for each answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a little method to read and check the users input from the command line:

```
public static List<String> readNLinesOfInput(int lines2Read){
    List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) { 
        while(inputs.size() < lines2Read) {
            System.out.println("Enter the "+(inputs.size()+1)+" line: ");
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if("".equals(line)){
                System.out.print("Empty lines a not allowed. ");
                continue;
            }
            inputs.add(line);
        }
    }
    return inputs;
}
```

You can call it and iterate over each line like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = readNLinesOfInput(50);
    for(String line: list){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks, makes my job much easier when it comes to adding more questions :3